# spliterator getExactSizeIfKnown vs estimateSize

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, spliterator

This came up as I was writing a custom `Spliterator`. I *know* I should override `estimateSize` if I know the size, even an approximative one. And usually, I do. But then there is `getExactSizeIfKnown` and I understand it's default implementation:

```
default long getExactSizeIfKnown() {
    return (characteristics() & SIZED) == 0 ? -1L : estimateSize();
}
```

Now, suppose I am working on an `ArrayListSpliterator` (I understand it already exists, that is not the point). Should I override `getExactSizeIfKnown` or `estimateSize` or may be even both?

Internally, I guess `getExactSizeIfKnown` is actually called, *not* `estimateSize` - since the first one delegates to the second. Taking into consideration that theoretically I am working on a `ArrayListSpliterator`, will *not* overriding `getExactSizeIfKnown` actually just make me pay for one extra method call - the detour `getExactSizeIfKnown` -> `estimateSize`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to “Should I override `getExactSizeIfKnown` or `estimateSize` or may be even both?” is, you *must* implement `estimateSize` as it is `abstract`. You may additionally override the `default` method `getExactSizeIfKnown` if you see a reason.

> Internally, I guess `getExactSizeIfKnown` is actually called, *not* `estimateSize` - since the first one delegates to the second.

It’s not that simple. Be prepared for code calling `getExactSizeIfKnown` because it may utilize that number only if being exact and hasn’t checked the characteristics. But at the same time there can be other code calling `estimateSize`, either because it *wants* an estimate or because it will processes the characteristics at another place. The fact that one has a `default` implementation that may delegate to the other under a certain condition doesn’t say anything about the caller. These methods have different semantics.

> Taking into consideration that theoretically I am working on a `ArrayListSpliterator`, will *not* overriding `getExactSizeIfKnown` actually just make me pay for one extra method call - the detour `getExactSizeIfKnown` -> `estimateSize`?

It’s likely that the *conditional* hurts more than a delegation call, but if your specific `Spliterator` invariably returns the same characteristics, the JVM’s optimizer likely eliminates any overhead connected with that. So it’s the usual trade-off, here, a tiny potential performance benefit over a tiny development effort (for providing an additional method just returning a known number).

If the calculation of the size is not trivial you would end up at delegation anyway, as you don’t want duplication of nontrivial code. And if your class is designed in a way that the `SIZED` characteristic is not always present, you would do exactly the same as the `default` method anyway.

Comment: *You may additionally override the default method getExactSizeIfKnown if you see a reason* - this is what itches... . I would implement it, why did they choose not to (in the jdk `ArrayListSpliterator`)? In so many other places too btw they choose not to do it, this was just an example

Comment: @Eugene as said, you're trading a tiny potential performance benefit (if any) over a tiny development effort. Perhaps it has been considered not worth it. Perhaps the `default` method was added when the classes already existed. Even a measurable difference on that method has almost no impact on the total time of a stream operation, considering how rarely it is called, compared to the relevant per-element operations.